# ExtJS property grid not showing after render listener

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I have a property grid I am creating an I have a listener on "afterrender" that looks something like this:

```
afterrender: function(){

                console.log(record);
                // im trying to get the record
                var gridValues = this.getSource();
                var store = this.getStore('teamMembers');
                store.clearFilter(true);
                store.addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
                store.addFilter({property: 'periodName', value: gridValues.periodName});
                /*
                var store = this.getStore('teamMembers');
                store.clearFilter(true);
                store.addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
                store.addFilter({property: 'periodName', value: gridvalues.periodName});
                */


                console.log(gridValues.resourcedFte);
                console.log(store.count());
                //this.getRecord();
```

My function is working correctly and doing what I want it to do for now, but after it has fired my property grids are not shown in my view. I have tried using doLayout() but that did not work.

Edit: the full code for my grid is:

```
var tempPropGrid = me.getView().add(
    {
        xtype:'propertygrid',
        width: 80,
        header: false,
        title: 'prop grid',
        //for some reason the headers are not hiding, we may need to deal with this using CSS
        //hideHeaders: true,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        sortableColumns: false,
        nameColumnWidth: 1,
        source: record.data,
        sourceConfig: {

            periodScrumMaster: {
                editor: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                    store: team,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField: 'personName',
                    valueField: 'personName',
                    listeners: {
'expand' : function(combo) {
                            var gridvalues = this.up('propertygrid').getSource();
                            combo.getStore().clearFilter(true);
                            combo.getStore().addFilter({property: 'teamName', value: teamName});
                            combo.getStore().addFilter({property: 'periodName', value: gridvalues.periodName});
                            var totalFTE = team.count();
                            console.log(totalFTE);
                        },
                    }}),
                displayName: 'Scrum Master'
            },
```

Comment: What is the layout of the parent container?

Comment: Hi, Can you rewrite your code putting the afterrender in the grid definition instead of giving two code blocks, maybe the error is in the way you are declaring your afterrender. It is very important that you past the code as is.